# Installing Tensorflow Versions Above 1.1.0 on Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to install Tensorflow version 1.2.0 or above so I can have access to 'feature_column'.

I've tried many things to try and update it but haven't been successful with any.

I'm using:

> Mac OS X El Capitan V10.11.5
>
> Anaconda version 1.7.0
>
> python version 3.6.4
>
> pip version 9.0.1

Here are some methods I tried:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 544, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 282, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 258, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 248, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 601, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 550, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 421, in _init_posix
    _temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), ['build_time_vars'], 0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_x86_64_apple_darwin13_4_0'
```

When that failed I tried this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

However, this only gave me the option to install Tensorflow version 1.1.0
```

Is there a reason it won't let me install version 1.2.0 or higher?

Comment: The error message in the pip installation command, the error seems to be coming from "sysconfig". Maybe this is relevant: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6648

Comment: I already tried that tutorial, and unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
conda install -c conda-forge google-api-python-client
```

Allow's Anaconda to find the latest versions of tensorflow

Then to upgrade tensorflow, I had to first downgrade html5lib to version 0.9999999

Answer (score 0):

the google-api-python client worked, but the version of tensorflow is still lower than the released version, as I get tensorflow 1.5 but 1.6 is out.
the following code worked for me:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
```